# How to count certain elements from a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of every session in each year.

`SELECT count(SUserSessionID) FROM test.transactions WHERE batch = 2011 OR batch = 2012 OR batch = 2013 OR batch = 2014 OR batch = 2015 OR batch = 2016 OR batch = 2017;`

Batch contains the date (YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS GMT). So how should I approach this?

EDIT: I also want the total number of count of every year to be the output.
Sorry in advance for any newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by on batch. Since batch is date time you need to extract year(in mysql you can use year function) and then had to do groupBy

SELECT batch, count(SUserSessionID) FROM test.transactions GROUP BY YEAR(batch);

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
SELECT 
batch, count(SUserSessionID)  
FROM  
test.transactions  
WHERE batch between 2011 and 2017 
group by batch;
```